# How do I prevent ServerXMLHTTP from automatically following redirects (HTTP 303 See Other responses)?

Tags: http, post, redirect, winhttp, serverxmlhttp

I am using ServerXMLHTTP to perform an HTTP POST. The response returned is a redirect (specifically 303 See Other). ServerXMLHTTP is automatically following this redirect but this is causing an authentication failure as is not propagating the Authorization header of the original request.

Is there a way I can prevent the automatic redirection (or alternatively ensure that the Authorization header is resent)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**ServerXMLHTTP does not support interception of redirects** (see [Microsoft Knowledge Base Article 308607](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308607)). However **WinHTTP** can be used in its place and this **does** contain a configurable 'enable redirects' option.

How to disable WinHTTP redirects in VBA:

```
webClient.Option(6) = False
```

In context:

```
Set webClient = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
webClient.Option(6) = False 
webClient.Open "POST", "http://example.com", False
webClient.send ("")
```