# WinINet: How to prevent HttpSendRequest to follow redirects (30x Status Codes)?

Tags: wininet

When I make an HTTP request with the method [HttpSendRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384247(VS.85).aspx) of the [WinINet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383630(VS.85).aspx) API, and the response sends "`302: Moved Temporarily`", the WinINet API automatically follows the redirection instruction and makes a new request.

**So, How to prevent HttpSendRequest to follow redirects (30x Status Codes)?**

I don't want't to make two requests... I wan't to get the the first response it got with the status code 302 in it's header.

Answer (score 2):

I found a flag `INTERNET_FLAG_NO_AUTO_REDIRECT` that I must pass to `HttpOpenRequest`.

But, it isn't working....

Answer (score 0):

Redirection can be prevented if you are able to use WinHTTP instead ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161343/how-do-i-prevent-serverxmlhttp-from-automatically-following-redirects-http-303-s/161970#161970)).

Answer (score 0):

Try using `INTERNET_FLAG_NO_AUTO_REDIRECT` in the call to `HttpSendRequest`.  Sounds like you're trying to use it from `HttpOpenRequest`.

I use this flag with `InternetOpenUrl`, and it works properly in that call.

Comment: I don't think this is the case.  HttpSendRequest does not accept a dwFlags parameter, and the flag is mentioned on the HttpOpenRequest msdn page.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384233(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Seems like WinInet behavior largely depends of `lpszAgent` specified in the `InternetOpen` function call. When you pass `"Mozilla/5.0 (compatible)"` all redirects are ignored and you will get RAW HTML result when reading response with `InternetReadFile`.

On the other hand, if you need "redirected" output, you must specify your application name in the Agent argument, for example `"ConEmu Update"`.