# Copy url from browser into Excel

Tags: vba, excel, url

My company uses short URLs for marketing campaigns, which redirect to URLs with tracking. For example:

> example.com/campaign

will redirect to:

> example.com/utm_source=**one**&utm_medium=**two**&utm_term=**three**&utm_content=**four**&utm_campaign=**five**

I have an excel file with a list of short URLs, but the tracking URLs are not listed. The current process is to manually open each link and copy the URL.

**Is there a way to copy the tracking URLs into excel using VBA?**

So far I've explored the following:

```
Dim ie As Object
Set ie = CreateObject("Internetexplorer.Application")
ie.Navigate Cells(1, 1)
```

But I can't find a way to then copy the new URL back into excel.

I've also tried:

```
Dim link As Hyperlink
Cells(1, 1).Select
Set link = ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add(Anchor:=Cells(1, 1), Address:=Cells(1, 1))
link.Follow
Cells(1, 2) = link.Address
```

However this just (unsurprisingly) brings back the original hyperlink.

How can I bring back the tracking URL? Ideally without having to install any other software (as my company's IT department is a nightmare) but if that's the only option then so be it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this will do what you want:

```
Set webClient = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
webClient.Option(6) = False
webClient.Open "GET", Cells(1, 1), False
webClient.send ("")
Cells(1, 2) = webClient.GetResponseHeader("Location")
```

I got the idea from this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161343/how-do-i-prevent-serverxmlhttp-from-automatically-following-redirects-http-303).

What you are trying to do is get the location you're redirecting to.

Redirects follow a standard process described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301)... and I'm just grabbing the appropriate header from the response.

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you. And thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You want the `.LocationURL` property

```
Const READYSTATE_COMPLETE As Long = 4
Dim IE As Object

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

IE.Navigate Cells(1, 1).Value

'// Wait for page to finish loading
While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Wend

Cells(1, 2).Value = IE.LocationURL
```